# $(this +"selector") ? $("img",this) possible?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to "select" a img inside a $(this) selector. I know I can find it by using `.find('img')` but is this possible:

`$("img",this)` ?

What's the most optimal way to do this?

Originally code

```
<a class="picture" href="test.html">
    <img src="picture.jpg" alt="awesome">
</a>
```

Comment: Both ways would work the same. I don't think it's meaningful to call any of the two "optimal".

Comment: BTW, you can always use the science: http://jsperf.com/jqslctrtst

Comment: True, they're the same, but .find() is a bit faster than context. 
http://jsperf.com/jquery-context-find-and-children-selectors/6
http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-context-2/2

Answer (score 73, accepted):

> What's the most optimal way to do this?

Both `$(this).find('img')` and `$('img', this)` are equivalent.

From the docs:

> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method,
>   so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span').

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 6):

That a perfect reasonably way of doing it.

So you would do like:

```
$('a').click( function() {
   //if the element dosent change you can use this
   //var src = $('img', this).attr('src');
   //else use $(this)
   var src = $('img', $(this)).attr('src');
   alert(src);
   return false;
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/xYmwV/

There is really no difference, since in both methods you load the dom element, and search it. Your way ofcourse is "cleaner" and simpler, but might be more confusing :)

A faster way would be `$(this).children()` since it then would'nt have to search for elements, but goes directly downwords in the DOM. But it takes out the flexibility of the script.

Comment: Sometimes you need to add `$(this)` instead of `this`, but basically that's the way to do this. +1 :)

Comment: @Phoenix Yea it makes sense to call the element when you search it. Never really understood why you don't normally need to call it? :/

Comment: Seems to be if you move in/out of the DOM `this` might change, where as `$('this')` will not. http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/

Comment: That's right. I also like to give my objects a variable of mine like: `img_var = $(this);` just to make sure. Sometimes inside functions such as `$.foreach()` `$(this)` also changes.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do that... anyway they're equivalent, so it's only a matter of your 'syntactic tastes':

> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method,
>   so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span').

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really matter, choose whichever you prefer, it's primarily a stylistic choice.

jQuery handles the form `$(selector, context)` by doing `$(context).find(selector)` or (if `context` is already a jQuery instance) `context.find(selector)` under the covers, so in theory the `find` form is ***slightly*** more efficient, but not in any way that's really likely to matter.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use `.find('img')`? it works to me : http://jsfiddle.net/nnmEY/

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to "select" a img inside a $(this) selector.

```
var myImg = $(this).find("img");
```