# Using 'this' in javascript with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm calling this php file  from Ajax and writing  the required javascript code in this php file.

```
<div class="add_people_invite">
    <button class="btn btn-default add_connection" id="right_connection_request" onclick="SentRequestMouseUpRight(event,{{ $peopleMayKnow->id }})">
        <span>My Text</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Javascript code :

```
<script>
    function SentRequestMouseUpRight(event, user_id) {
        if (event.which == 1) {
            alert();
            $("#right_connection_request span", this).text("My NEW Text");
        }
    }
</script>
```

alert in javascript is working but it is not changing the text to My NEW Text and if I remove `this` and then I run this code `$("#right_connection_request span").text("My NEW Text");` It changes the text.

Comment: Why do you need `this` here anyway? You're using an ID and IDs as such must be unique.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have *aynthing* to do with ajax.

Comment: If you want `this` to refer to the clicked element, you'd need to use `.call(this, …`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.target` instead of `this` keyword.
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/kkn0xzqf/) is a fiddle to demonstrate the same.

```
function SentRequestMouseUpRight(event, user_id) {
  if (event.which == 1) {
    $(event.target).text("My NEW Text");
  }
}
```

Comment: if I want to change onlick function then $(event.target).setAttribute('onclick','writeLED(1,1)') ,this will also work.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this first, [$(this +"selector") ? $("img",this) possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187280/this-selector-img-this-possible)

The answer as to why it works one way but not the other I cant really tell by lookign at your example we will need to look at what version of Jquery you are using and a few other factors.

Comment: I had tried this too : $("span", this).text("My NEW Text"); but not working.

Answer (score 0):

u can change html also if you dont want to change ur javascript, else accepted answer is correct.

`<div class="add_people_invite">
    <button class="btn btn-default add_connection" id="right_connection_request" onclick="return SentRequestMouseUpRight(this,{{ $peopleMayKnow->id }});">
        <span>My Text</span>
    </button>
</div>`

'this' is window object in both cases.